# HTML and Body are not taking up the entire browser - HTML5 problem?

Tags: css, xhtml, html

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, but for some reason, I'm experiencing a bug with my markup that is causing my body element and my html element to not take up the entire viewport in the browser.

I can't get to the bottom of this. It first reared its head when I tried to add a 10px purple border to the top and bottom of my body.

If you inspect the page in Firebug, you you can see that there's a huge chunk of the page that is not highlighted when you hover on the html element or the body element. And the border that I applied at the bottom is hanging up very far on the page.

Does anyone know why this is? Could it have to do with my using HTML5?

Here's the page in question:
http://electricorangecreative.com/test/index.html

And here are my style sheets:
http://electricorangecreative.com/test/reset.css
http://electricorangecreative.com/test/style.css

Comment: I don’t think this is an HTML5 thing: change your doctype to XHTML 1.0, and you should see the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [sticky footer technique](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).

Comment: Explanation: the borders are added to the 100% height of the `body`, thereby causing the page to be taller than the viewport. You can add a `div` at the top, functioning as a border, and a similar div at the bottom (see meder's link).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I believe that I have the sticky footer working, but it's still creating the vertical scrollbar and the footer is always below the fold: http://electricorangecreative.com/test/index.html

Comment: It seems like the 100% height on the Wrapper div is causing this problem. And, I was able to get the sticky footer working just fine, so long as the border on the bottom was contained to the width of page and within the footer (this is how it is on meder's sticky footer link). I was hoping to have this work so that the border went all the way across the top and bottom of the viewport. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look at the current test page and it looks like the only outstanding issue is the vertical scrollbar still appearing without need to. Easiest fix for this is to simply remove any margin or padding you have on elements you've set to `height:100%`. The culprit I identified is `div#wrapper`. Take off the padding there and the issue is resolved (in FF at least - not tested on other browsers). Since the padding is added to the height you end up with an element that stretches over 100% vertically. Use margins on children instead of padding - should be fine!